# Selenium IDE: How to assert attribute exists

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE.

I know how to test if an element's attribute has a certain value. But how do I test if the attribute exists in the first place?

Here is the line which successfully tests if the attribute has a certain value:

```
<tr>
    <td>assertAttribute</td>
    <td>id=_ctl0_MainPlaceHolder_dgMemberList_DXSelBtn0@disabled</td>
    <td>disabled</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the line which unsuccessfully tests if the attribute exists in the first place:

```
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=_ctl0_MainPlaceHolder_dgMemberList_DXSelBtn0@disabled</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

How do I get it to work?

Thank,

-Ilya

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "getAttribute" method, and if it returns "null" it means that there is no attribute at all...

From Selenium documentation:

```
WebElement.getAttribute( attributeName ) → Thenable<(string|null)>
```

Schedules a command to query for the value of the given attribute of the element. Will return the current value, even if it has been modified after the page has been loaded. More exactly, this method will return the value of the given attribute, unless that attribute is not present, in which case the value of the property with the same name is returned. If neither value is set, null is returned (for example, the "value" property of a textarea element). The "style" attribute is converted as best can be to a text representation with a trailing semi-colon.

For example:

HTML code:

```
<div id="a"         >1</div>
<div id="a" x="xxx" >2</div>
<div id="a" x       >3</div>
```

Test code in Nodejs:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var capabilitiesObj = {
    'browserName'     : 'firefox'
};
var driver          = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(capabilitiesObj).build();
driver.get('http://localhost/customer.js/temp/index60.html');

driver.findElements(webdriver.By.css('div[id=a]')).then((elements) => {
    elements[0].getAttribute('x').then((att)=> {
        console.log(att);
    });

}).catch(console.log.bind(console));

driver.quit();
```

The result for each div will be different:

```
for div 1: null
for div 2: 'xxx'
for div 3: ''
```

Comment: He tagged it with both Selenium & Selenium IDE but the question was asking for an IDE solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the simple id locator handles the attribute. So switch to xpath:

This should work:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>xpath=//.[@id='id3' and @attribute1]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Note that if you change the specific id (id1, id2, id3) it will pass for the first 2 ids but fail for the 3rd:

```
<div id="id1" attribute1="xyz" style="background-color: transparent;">Some text</div>
<div id="id2" attribute1="" style="background-color: transparent;">Some text</div>
<div id="id3" style="background-color: transparent;">Some text</div>
```